# How can I get ASP.NET MVC to generate fields for foreign keys in EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an EF model with a table with several foreign keys.  These foreign keys are managed by associations.  In code, I can get a strongly typed list of objects when I access that property on the object.

When I generate a strongly typed view, all I see are the int fields.  Is there a way to get ASP.NET MVC to bind to the objects that are related as well as the main object?

Comment: Try removing the foreign keys from the actual model - you don't need them there if you have the navigational properties.

Comment: If you do, the actual integer fields go away from the views but nothing else happens.  Is the default model binder just not able to bind to complex types?

Answer (score 1):

check this presentation from Brad Wilson [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 4: Custom Object Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html), if you're using MVC2, you could write a custom Object Template.